# Jenkins stapler requests fail with no valid crumb

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, csrf, hudson, hudson-plugins

I'm working on a Jenkins plugin and I'm now stuck at a point where I'm trying to get the return value of a method using a JavaScript proxy as described [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AJAX+with+JavaScript+proxy).

I simply want to call this kotlin method:

```
@JavaScriptMethod
fun getMonitoredJobsAsJSON(): JSONArray = toJSON(getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(getMonitoredJobs())) as JSONArray
```

From the jelly script using this:

```
<script>
  var board = <st:bind value="${it}"/>

  board.getMonitoredJobsAsJSON(function(data) {
   //
  })
</script>
```

This actually works when I disable CSRF protection on the Jenkins server but I obviously don't want to do that. With CSRF protection on I always get a no valid crumb found 403 error:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/$stapler/bound/36dc05fc-c12d-4182-a008-60bcf5c49307/getMonitoredJobsAsJSON 403 (No valid crumb was included in the request)
```

I know how to retrieve crumbs from the `crumbIssuer` end point for interacting with the Jenkins rest api but I've found virtually no resources on how to make it work for stapler requests in plugins.

Also, when I inspect the requests, a crumb header is actually set in the request:
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: See if this helps ? https://github.com/Rajkumarhouston/Jenkins/blob/7f27a5e2119bc28951717b6c815502cbfff93ac6/core/src/main/resources/lib/layout/html.jelly and https://github.com/mwitcraft/BuildMonitorView/blob/1559ec9b7b1db3aa9e01b1fcad32af0d9471d4a4/build-monitor-plugin/src/main/resources/com/smartcodeltd/jenkinsci/plugins/buildmonitor/BuildMonitorView/index.jelly

Comment: Did you look at the two links i posted?

Comment: Hey, yeah I did, I didn't get much from the first link but I'm spending more time to work up a possible solution from the second one, it basically does what I'm trying to achieve but I don't have a clear of understanding of what is actually happening yet. Thanks for the links!

Comment: I don't have the setup to try those, thats why I thought it might help you explore a solution

Comment: What is the ```plugin name```? Have you ever read it? https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API#RemoteaccessAPI-CSRFProtection

Comment: Thanks guys. Finally found a solution to this, thanks for your links!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weeks later, I finally found a solution to this.

The problem was that for some reason, the name of the crumb header appended to the requests by default is actually wrong. It's `Crumb` as shown in the screenshot in my question, but it actually should be `Jenkins-Crumb` or `.crumb` for older versions of Jenkins.

What I did was to find a way to retrieve a crumb **and the correct header name** from the server when the page is loading initially, and then append this crumb header using the correct name to any subsequent xhr requests.

I defined an entity for the crumbs:

```
class RemoteRequestCrumb {
    @JsonIgnore private val crumbIssuer: CrumbIssuer? = Jenkins.getInstance()?.getCrumbIssuer()
    val fieldName: String? = crumbIssuer?.crumbRequestField
    val crumbValue: String? = crumbIssuer?.crumb
}
```

And then add this entity to the plugin as an attribute:

```
fun getRemoteRequestCrumb(): JSONObject = toJSON(
    SerializationUtils.getObjectWriter().writeValueAsString(RemoteRequestCrumb())
) as JSONObject
```

Now you can request the crumb data from a jelly script as with any other plugin attribute: `${it.getRemoteRequestCrumb()}`.

The last step is actually appending the correct header to all XHR requests:

```
appendCrumbHeaderToAllRequests: function () {
  let crumb = JSON.parse(this.remoteRequestCrumb);
  let open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    let mutatedPrototype = open.apply(this, arguments);
    this.setRequestHeader(crumb.fieldName, crumb.crumbValue);
    return mutatedPrototype;
  }
}
```